# How to store currency values and format their output in julia-lang?

Tags: julia

At the moment I'm storing currency amounts in type `::Float64`, the majoirty of amounts are in the billions to hundreds-of-millions in differing currency units. In other use-cases I also have it that currency values are necessary to be kept in tens-of-thousands of a unit of currency, e.g 0.7564

However, given the rounding errors associated double-precision-floating numbers, should I be converting everything into fixed-point integers for storing the currency units?

Secondly, how do you format the string output of an currency unit, and allow for the relevant currency symbol to be displayed?

Secondly, are their any packages that provide a "currency" data type that would be safe to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a really basic starting point for storing currency and displaying it:

```
immutable Currency
  symbol::Symbol
  amount::Int
end

function Base.show(io::IO, c::Currency)
  print(io, c.symbol, c.amount/100)
end

Currency(:£, 1275) #=> £12.75
```

This stores the currency as an exact value in pennies, so no rounding error, but displays it in the usual way. You could of course easily parameterise on the number of decimal places to store. I can't answer as to whether you *should* use fixed point numbers like this, but they'll certainly be more accurate for addition, subtraction and multiplication.

As for prior art, a quick google for "currency.jl" turned up [this](https://github.com/aviks/Ito.jl) – it looks way out of date but might be useful as a reference.

Comment: I think this currently the best way to do it, I don't think I've seen a package with currency pretty printing / math. I'd swap out the `Int` in `amount::Int` with one of the types in https://github.com/JeffBezanson/FixedPointNumbers.jl though.

Comment: Definitely a good recommendation – that could save a lot of time having to overload arithmetic etc. for the currency type.

Comment: What is gained by using the `FixedPointNumbers` that isn't shown in the above answer? Wouldn't the operators for the abstract `Int` be sufficient?

Comment: For the most part it's unlikely to matter as it doesn't make much sense to multiply currencies. But you will have to override some behaviour (e.g. printing, as above), and FPN gives you that for free.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely not be using floating point numbers for currencies — you should define your own fixed-point numeric type, and use that.  The Julia manual has a good tutorial about defining a new numeric type in the chapter about conversions and promotions.

Let's assume that you will only ever need two digits after the decimal point — never mind pounds, shillings and pence.  Your new type will look something like

```
immutable Monetary <: Number
    hundredths :: Int64
end

Monetary(ones :: Int64, hundredths :: Int64) = Monetary(hundredths + 100 * ones)
```

Obviously, you'll want to be able to display monetary mounts:

```
Base.show(io :: IO, x :: Monetary) =
    @printf(io, "%lld.%02lld", fld(x.hundredths, 100), mod(x.hundredths, 100))
```

you'll also want to be able to add and subtract them:

```
+(x :: Monetary, y :: Monetary) = Monetary(x.hundredths + y.hundredths)
-(x :: Monetary, y :: Monetary) = Monetary(x.hundredths - y.hundredths)
```

On the other hand, you'll never want to multiply them ­— but multiplying a monetary sum by an integer is fine:

```
*(x :: Bool, y :: Monetary) = ifelse(x, y, Monetary(0))
*(x :: Monetary, y :: Bool) = ifelse(y, x, Monetary(0))
*(x :: Integer, y :: Monetary) = Monetary(x * y.hundredths)
*(x :: Monetary, y :: Integer) = Monetary(x.hundredths * y)
```

Finally, if you mix integers with monetary sums in an expression, it's fine to convert everything to monetary values:

```
Base.convert(::Type{Monetary}, x :: Int64) = Monetary(x, 0)
Base.promote_rule(::Type{Monetary}, ::Type{Int64}) = Monetary
```

This is good enough to perform useful computations:

```
julia> Scrooge.Monetary(30,5) * 3 + 12
102.15
```

but will reliably catch incorrect operations:

```
julia> Scrooge.Monetary(30,5) * 3.5
ERROR: no promotion exists for Monetary and Float64
 in * at ./promotion.jl:159
```

Answer (score 1):

[Currencies.jl](https://github.com/TotalVerb/Currencies.jl) provides an interface for working with currencies:

```
using Currencies
@usingcurrencies USD
format(1.23USD + 4.56USD, styles=[:us, :brief])  # $5.79
```

It supports type-safe arithmetic, currency conversion, and flexible pretty-printing.

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of Currencies.jl.

Comment: Thanks will look into it